# Getting error "Incompatibe types"

Tags: java

I am new to Java programming and testing contains method used in ArrayList. As I am passing objects through the contains method, I am overriding the equals method of Object class but while doing that I am getting the following error
**Incompatible types:Object cannot be converted to checkHole**

Following is the code I have written

```
import java.util.*;

class checkHole
{
    public int a, b;
    public checkHole (int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int getA()
    {
        return this.a;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {

        if(o instanceof checkHole)
        {
            return ((checkHole)o).getA().equals(this.a);

        }
        else 
            return false;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<checkHole> aList = new ArrayList<checkHole>();

        aList.add(new checkHole(0,1));
        aList.add(new checkHole(2,3));
        aList.add(new checkHole(4,5));

        checkHole h = new checkHole(0,1);
        boolean x = aList.contains(h);  // x = true if the objects are equal by value

        System.out.println(x); // Should print true if the objects are equal
    }
}
```

I have been searching about the above casting issue for quite sometime but in vain.Almost everywhere the equals method is used in a similar fashion.(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html)

I don't know why I am not able to cast the obj to checkHole type.

Comment: Post the exact and complete error message, and tell us which line it refers to. Also, indent your code properly, and respect the Java naming conventions: classes start with an uppercase letter. `x= true if the objects are equal by value`is obviously invalid Java code. If that is supposed to be a comment, then make it a comment, as you did the line after.

Comment: BTW, maybe It had a long time since I wrote a Java code, but shouldn't you use the '==' operator instead of the equals methods while using primitive types like int? so ((checkHole)o).getA() == this.a

Comment: I don't have ide but seems u are calling equals on int primitive type and it may cause problem

Comment: Is this the exact copy of your code? As other have mentioned, it cannot be compiled because it tries to invoke a method (equals) on a primitive type (int).
Other than that, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the .Equals() to ==. When you are using primitive types (int, char, boolean), use ==. When using object references (CheckHole, any kind of class you create), use .equals().

```
if(o instanceof checkHole)
{
    return ((checkHole)o).getA()==this.a;
}
```